# Can't change shadow method

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

In the Render menu in Blender, there is supposed to be an option under Shadows that lets you change the method from VSM to ESM, so I can have less jagged shadows in Eevee.  However, for me, the option isn't there.  How do you make it appear?
[image]

Comment: That option was removed

Comment: Seconded - VSM and ESM were removed and replaced by PCF. It seems one of the primary concerns with the previous 2 systems was unacceptable light-bleed, which PCF is designed to eliminate (among other things).